# How to assert a type of an HTMLElement in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-assertion, typescript-types, typescript-lib-dom

I'm trying to do this:

```
var script:HTMLScriptElement = document.getElementsByName("script")[0];
alert(script.type);
```

but it's giving me an error:

```
Cannot convert 'Node' to 'HTMLScriptElement': Type 'Node' is missing property 'defer' from type 'HTMLScriptElement'
(elementName: string) => NodeList
```

I can't access the 'type' member of the script element unless I cast it to the correct type, but I don't know how to do this. I searched the docs & samples, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Note that this casting issue no longer exists in 0.9 - See answer by @Steve below.

Comment: @GregGum  I'm not seeing an answer by a Steve

Answer (score 285, accepted):

TypeScript uses '<>' to surround casts, so the above becomes:

```
var script = <HTMLScriptElement>document.getElementsByName("script")[0];
```

However, unfortunately you cannot do:

```
var script = (<HTMLScriptElement[]>document.getElementsByName(id))[0];
```

You get the error

```
Cannot convert 'NodeList' to 'HTMLScriptElement[]'
```

But you can do :

```
(<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName(id))[0];
```

Comment: i think they should look into this further, suppose you use $('[type:input]').each( function(index,element) and you need element to be cast to HTMLInputElement or HTMLSelectElement depending on which property you need to set/get, casting use (<HTMLSelectElement><any>element).selectedIndex=0; adds () around element , kind of ugly

Comment: +1 that answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669404/typescript-problems-with-type-system

Comment: In the long run (after 0.9 is out) you should be able to cast it to something like NodeList<HtmlScriptElement>, plus getElementsByName will be able to use string literal type overrides to get this right without any casting at all!

Comment: any is just huge, without ts would just be a joke

Comment: after 1.0, the syntax should be ```(<NodeListOf<HTMLScriptElement>>document.getElementsByName(id))[0];```

Comment: `any` is the bridge, but it shouldn't be applied here. `NodeList` is not an array of `Node`, and shouldn't be treated as an array. A better way would be `<Node[]>Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);`

Comment: Thank you. I'm sad that it has to be done like this, but it works. Better than nothing:/

Comment: You can also use as to cast. var script = document.getElementsByName("script")[0] as HTMLScriptElement;

Comment: The recommended type to use is `HTMLInputElement` according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10453.

Answer (score 52):

Do not type cast. Never. Use type guards:

```
const e = document.getElementsByName("script")[0];
if (!(e instanceof HTMLScriptElement)) 
  throw new Error(`Expected e to be an HTMLScriptElement, was ${e && e.constructor && e.constructor.name || e}`);
// locally TypeScript now types e as an HTMLScriptElement, same as if you casted it.
```

Let the compiler do the work for you and get errors when your assumptions turn out wrong.

It may look overkill in this case, but it will help you a lot if you come back later and change the selector, like adding a class that is missing in the dom, for example.

Comment: It would seem safe here, surely? We can guarantee that e is always going to be an instance of HTMLScriptElement, can't we (unless it doesn't exist, I suppose)?

Comment: I couldn't seem to get any type casting to work but this worked.

Comment: Casting is a sign you cannot programatically assert a type. In this case, you can programatically assert a type, so you should not cast. If you cast, you have a leaky type system and it will break eventually.

Comment: I have found that TS does not recognize the type in a nested `querySelector` (e.g. `document.querySelector("p > a")`) in which case angle bracket type assertions are acceptable.

Answer (score 36):

As of TypeScript 0.9 the `lib.d.ts` file uses specialized overload signatures that return the correct types for calls to `getElementsByTagName`.

This means you no longer need to use type assertions to change the type:

```
// No type assertions needed
var script: HTMLScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
alert(script.type);
```

Comment: how do you do it in object notation? ie I can't do **{name: <HTMLInputElement> : document.querySelector('#app-form [name]').value,}**

Comment: this worked:       name: (<HTMLInputElement> document.querySelector('#app-form [name]')).value,

Answer (score 21):

You always can hack type system using:

```
var script = (<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName(id))[0];
```

Comment: using <any> allows escaping type checking, not ideal but cool while in development

Answer (score 17):

We could type our variable with an *explicit return type*:

```ts
const script: HTMLScriptElement = document.getElementsByName(id).item(0);
```

Or assert ***as*** (needed with *TSX*):

```ts
const script = document.getElementsByName(id).item(0) as HTMLScriptElement;
```

Or in simpler cases assert with *angle-bracket* syntax.

---

> A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler.

Documentation:

[TypeScript - Basic Types - Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: Tks! the second option work for me. The first option my lint print:  Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLScriptElement'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLScriptElement'. (is my first project em Typescript :S hahaha)

Answer (score 14):

Rather than using a type assertion, type guard, or `any` to work around the issue, a more elegant solution would be to use *generics* to indicate the type of element you're selecting.

Unfortunately, `getElementsByName` is not generic, but `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are. (`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are also far more flexible, and so might be preferable in most cases.)

If you pass a tag name alone into `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`, it will automatically be typed properly due to the following line in `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
querySelector<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] | null;
```

For example, to select the first script tag on the page, as in your question, you can do:

```
const script = document.querySelector('script')!;
```

And that's it - TypeScript can now infer that `script` is now an `HTMLScriptElement`.

Use `querySelector` when you need to select a single element. If you need to select multiple elements, use `querySelectorAll`. For example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('script')
```

results in a type of `NodeListOf<HTMLScriptElement>`.

If you need a more complicated selector, you can pass a type parameter to indicate the type of the element you're going to select. For example:

```
const ageInput = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('form input[name="age"]')!;
```

results in `ageInput` being typed as an `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: But how is this any better than a normal type assertion? It's just a more obfuscated form of type assertion.

Comment: Type *assertions* are inherently unsafe. TS will happily let you do `const foo = {} as HTMLElement; foo.style.background = 'green';` and a runtime error will result. No matter the situation, utilizing generics is a much better choice when possible because they don't allow you to use *just anything* - they'll only allow you to use a type that the function permits. Generics are a core part of the type system and are used everywhere - I don't think calling them an obfuscation is fair.

Comment: Adding sensible constraints to how a value or function can be used and working within those constraints is one of the larger benefits of TypeScript. You don't want to do `const fn = (num: any) => {` - you want `const fn = (num: number) => {` to be precise and prevent yourself from making mistakes. For similar reasons, you should use generics instead of `as`.

Comment: Yes, it is constrained. And it's still just a hidden type assert, and still as unsafe as a normal assert. There's nothing preventing you from using a wrong type as a generic, then accessing a non existing property, resulting in a runtime error.

Comment: Also i haven't called generics an obfuscation, i called your use of it in this situation an obfuscated type assert.

Answer (score 13):

To end up with:

- an actual `Array` object (not a `NodeList` dressed up as an `Array`)
- a list that is guaranteed to only include `HTMLElements`, not `Node`s force-casted to `HTMLElement`s
- a warm fuzzy feeling to do The Right Thing

Try this:

```
let nodeList : NodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
let elementList : Array<HTMLElement> = [];

if (nodeList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        let node : Node = nodeList[i];

        // Make sure it's really an Element
        if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            elementList.push(node as HTMLElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify, this is correct.

> Cannot convert 'NodeList' to 'HTMLScriptElement[]'

as a `NodeList` is not an actual array (e.g. it doesn't contain `.forEach`, `.slice`, `.push`, etc...).

Thus if it did convert to `HTMLScriptElement[]` in the type system, you'd get no type errors if you tried to call `Array.prototype` members on it at compile time, but it would fail at run time.

Comment: granted that is correct, however not entirely useful. the alternative is to go via 'any' which provides no useful type checking whatsoever...

Answer (score 3):

This seems to solve the problem, using the `[index: TYPE]` array access type, cheers.

```
interface ScriptNodeList extends NodeList {
    [index: number]: HTMLScriptElement;
}

var script = ( <ScriptNodeList>document.getElementsByName('foo') )[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the sitepen guides

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript/ (see below) and
https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/08/22/advanced-typescript-concepts-classes-types/

> TypeScript also allows you to specify different return types when an
>   exact string is provided as an argument to a function. For example,
>   TypeScript’s ambient declaration for the DOM’s createElement method
>   looks like this:

```
createElement(tagName: 'a'): HTMLAnchorElement;
createElement(tagName: 'abbr'): HTMLElement;
createElement(tagName: 'address'): HTMLElement;
createElement(tagName: 'area'): HTMLAreaElement;
// ... etc.
createElement(tagName: string): HTMLElement;
```

> This means, in TypeScript, when you call e.g.
>   document.createElement('video'), TypeScript knows the return value is
>   an HTMLVideoElement and will be able to ensure you are interacting
>   correctly with the DOM Video API without any need to type assert.

Answer (score 1):

Could be solved in the declaration file (lib.d.ts) if TypeScript would define HTMLCollection instead of NodeList as a return type.

DOM4 also specifies this as the correct return type, but older DOM specifications are less clear.

See also http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/252

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350719/11407695), if you utilize [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment the standard definition library's `Document` interface, you can add a generic override for the `getElementsByName` method (or for any other for that matter) with parameter default set to `HTMLElement` to mimic the behaviour of the non-generic version when the type argument is not provided explicitly:

```ts
interface Document
  extends Node,
    DocumentAndElementEventHandlers,
    DocumentOrShadowRoot,
    GlobalEventHandlers,
    NonElementParentNode,
    ParentNode,
    XPathEvaluatorBase {
  getElementsByName<T extends HTMLElement>(elementName: string) : NodeListOf<T>;
}
```

Then in the user code you can explicitly pass the desired type:

```ts
const scripts = document.getElementsByName<HTMLScriptElement>("name"); //NodeListOf<HTMLScriptElement>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEFcC2FwBQyyEAHpCACYDOyAcupRADRHFqa75gCCVAogBsIecPwBu3ABJwqwqNVbsO2UWADyUAMoALOJXQB3AErp0YJewDig9ACM4gidNmV5itsQYghI7gAU4KG4GJktiQODwUJZPZAANQLAdCUcsODB0KAAhOGoUAG82AHMIMF81amyATzo4PAAeABUScnwaZCkmgFkAGQruAD4ACghhNTq8AC5kajAoUGKASmQZmN7gOfUYZsGAbgIAXwICBHQQOdmEBYAHMFoAXmQDVW4AOlLy8e4q2vqIBpdPpaa7AO4DcAjABEIH%20UKWe2QAHoketNhodkDeiDbl8-JCgA)

---

Note that you need to respecify the `extends` list because only identical declarations can be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `NodeList`, not an `Array`, you shouldn't really be using brackets or casting to `Array`. The property way to get the first node is:

```
document.getElementsByName(id).item(0)
```

You can just cast that:

```
var script = <HTMLScriptElement> document.getElementsByName(id).item(0)
```

Or, extend `NodeList`:

```
interface HTMLScriptElementNodeList extends NodeList
{
    item(index: number): HTMLScriptElement;
}
var scripts = <HTMLScriptElementNodeList> document.getElementsByName('script'),
    script = scripts.item(0);
```

Comment: UPDATE
Casting now looks like this:


`const script = document.getElementsByName(id).item(0) as HTMLScriptElement;`

Comment: That is, "looks  like this" for TS 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = (<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName(id))[0];
```