# Can't retrieve ion-input value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

How do I retrieve an ion-input value in Ionic 2?

In my **example.html** I have this:

```
<ion-input value="hello" type="text" id="ion1"></ion-input>
```

While in **example.ts** I tried in this way, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement) (maybe outdated) question:

```
let inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ion1")).value;
```

But I get `undefined` in `google chrome` console.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable two way binding over your `ion-input` by doing adding `[(ngModel)]`

```
<ion-input>
  <ion-label>Enter text...</ion-label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" />
</ion-input>
```

Then inside Component class you could specify value for `searchInput` property.

---

Other way would be

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"></ion-input>
```