# How get the value of Hidden from MVC view in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How get the value of hidden input that is in MVC view, in the JavaScript/Type Script File? Without use of jQuery please.

This is my input:

```
 <input type="hidden" value="@Model.GridHeader" name="gridheader" id="gridheader" />
 <input type="hidden" value="@Model.GridData" name="griddata" id="griddata" />
```

I tried these but non are working, they all return null value.

```
window.onload = function () {
var gridheader = document.getElementById("gridheader").innerHTML;
var griddata = document.getElementById("griddata").innerHTML;
alert(gridheader );
```

I already tried `innerText` and `textContent`.

Comment: Swap `.innerHTML` for `.value` inputs have values, not inner content/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `input` element hasn't an `innerHTML` property but a `value` attribute. So changing your code as below:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var gridheader = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("gridheader")).value;
    var griddata = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("griddata")).value;
    alert(gridheader);
}
```

it would work.

You could read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

> property 'value' does not exists on type 'HTMLElement' It gave me
>   this, maybe because it is TypeScirpt?

Above I prepended the document.getElemementById(...) with . I wasn't aware of this, since I have no experience with TypeScript. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement).

Comment: @fubbe `<button>` will have inner content but that isn't an input is it... this is a button input `<input type="button" value="My Button"/>` which has a `value`

Comment: property 'value' does not exists on type 'HTMLElement' It gave me this, maybe because it is TypeScirpt?

Comment: Please see my update. I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement So if that will work, please make an upvote also at this link :) and let me know, in order to upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Got that work with:

```
 var inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('gridheader')).value;
```