# why we are using HTMLInputElement in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why we are using:

```
(document.getElementById("ipv") as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("ipv").value;
```

?

Comment: `getElementById` returns an `Element` ... an `Element` does not have a `value`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12989808/3991628) should clarify things a bit. The gist of it is that typescript has no way of knowing that the element is an `HTMLInputElement` rather than a generic `HTMLElement` unless you tell it so. An `HTMLElement` doesn't have a `value` property, but an `HTMLInputElement` does, so it needs to be cast to that type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function `getElementById` returns object with type `HTMLElement`.

From lib.dom.d.ts:

```
 /**
 * Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID or NAME attribute.
 * @param elementId String that specifies the ID value. Case-insensitive.
 */
getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null;
```

`HTMLElement` type is the base type for the other tag types of the DOM.
For example, the type `HTMLInputElement` extends `HTMLElement` and have the property `value` that the type `HTMLElement` doesn't have.

From lib.dom.d.ts:

```
interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement {
...
/**
 * Returns the value of the data at the cursor's current position.
 */
value: string;
...
```

Since `HTMLInputElement` extends `HTMLElement`, the next lines can compile:

```
const inputTag = document.getElementById('name-input') as HTMLInputElement;
const value = inputTag.value;
```

Answer (score 14):

`document.getElementById()` won't be able to return a specific element type since it doesn't know in advance what that element will be, so you need to cast the result as an HTMLInputElement after the fact so that the `value` property of that class can be recognized.