# Get textbox caret position on screen - selectionStart does not exist on type HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project and I want to get the caret position in a textarea on the screen so I can display a container near to the cursor but everything I google says to get the element using `getElementById` and then calling `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd` to get the cursor position.

But whenever I try that I get the error saying selectionStart does not exist on the type HTMLElement.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
const elem = document.getElementById("text1") as HTMLElement;
var curPos = elem.selectionStart;
```

I've also tried removing the `as HTMLElement` in case that makes a difference but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("text1") as HTMLInputElement`?

Comment: Ah that it, didn't realise you had to differentiate between a normal element and input element, thought everything was an HTMLelement

Comment: [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325987/7867822) explain it well

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Learn something new everyday :)