# How to set mask textfield cursor at start position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masking

I'm using react mask textfield component . When I click on it , input cursor always shows up at the end of the mask . How to make when input is focused set that cursor after "+7(" ?

```
 <MaskedTextfield
    inputId="masktextfield"
    className="tf"
    reference={this.props.reference}
    maskedValue={this.props.maskedValue}
    numOfErrorMsgs={1}
    showMask
    guide
  />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove `guide` or set it to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setSelectionRange(0,0);`. 
First get the reference to the element, then apply that function. In plain JS the onFocus or onClick function would be like this:

```
var textfield = document.getElementById('masktextfield');
textfield.setSelectionRange(0,0);
```

Comment: there is an error " property 'setselectionrange' does not exist on type 'htmlelement' "

Comment: Maybe you need to cast the value to HTMLInputElement [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement)

Comment: thanks, I've fixed. But there is still a problem. If set setSelectionRange(4,4) it still shows cursor at the end, but with (4,5) as in the picture above(just added) it shows with selection. How to make it without selection?

Comment: Thats what `setSelectionRange` does, if you set it to 4,5 then one character is selected. 4,4 should set the cursor at position 4(zero-based index) I don't know why it is failing. Testing it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGmaEK?&editable=true) it works as intended.