# read SMS for automatically in ionic4 not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

I used the [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms-receive) plugin to read the SMS for OTP.
I am sending the SMS on the mobile number and then next screen I need to read the OTP number from the SMS and need to click on the Validate Pin.
But somehow the code is not executing this event `document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e: any) => {`

and then stuck here.

I am sharing the code also.

```
declare var SMSReceive: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.next();
  }

  OTP: string = '';
  OTPmessage: string = 'An OTP is sent to your number. You should receive it in 15 s'

  next() {
    this.start();
  }

  start() {
    alert("start");
    SMSReceive.startWatch(
      () => {
        console.log('watch started');
        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e: any) => {
          console.log('onSMSArrive()');
          alert('onSMSArrive()');
          var IncomingSMS = e.data;
          console.log('sms.address:' + IncomingSMS.address);
          console.log('sms.body:' + IncomingSMS.body);
          alert('sms.address:' + IncomingSMS.address);
          alert('sms.body:' + IncomingSMS.body);
          /* Debug received SMS content (JSON) */
          console.log(JSON.stringify(IncomingSMS));
          alert(JSON.stringify(IncomingSMS));
          this.processSMS(IncomingSMS);
        });
      },
      () => { console.log('watch start failed') }
    )
  }

  stop() {
    SMSReceive.stopWatch(
      () => { console.log('watch stopped') },
      () => { console.log('watch stop failed') }
    )
  }

  processSMS(data) {
    // Check SMS for a specific string sequence to identify it is you SMS
    // Design your SMS in a way so you can identify the OTP quickly i.e. first 6 letters
    // In this case, I am keeping the first 6 letters as OTP
    const message = data.body;
    if (message && message.indexOf('enappd_starters') != -1) {
      this.OTP = data.body.slice(0, 6);
      console.log(this.OTP);
      alert(this.OTP);
      this.OTPmessage = 'OTP received. Proceed to register'
      this.stop();
    }
  }
```

but the code is not executing addEventListener event.

Getting this error.

> SMSReceive is not defined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   ReferenceError: SMSReceive is not defined

Comment: Did you take permission of SMS reading from user?

Comment: yes. And it's asking to read the permission of SMS.

Comment: Have you tried logging this at the start of `start()`: `console.log(SMSReceive);` to be sure that your code is what you think, because declaring it as `any` will hide any issues.

Comment: I updated the question with console.log of SMSReceive.

Comment: i am trying it in ionic 6 but it gives me the same error, did you managed to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

- just ( Cast Types ) of SMSReceive it will help,
  you may check link of type cast
  [The property 'value' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement)