# Typehinting jQuery methods for PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, type-hinting

I'm having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement) but I am using JavaScript, not TypeScript so the solutions there don't apply.

With the following code:

```js
$("input").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log(el.value);
});
```

I get a complaint about `el.value`:

> Unresolved variable value

This is because jQuery type hints `el` as an `HTMLElement` but the `value` property is only present on certain child classes like `HTMLInputElement`.

The only way I've found to quiet this warning is something like this, which I'm not crazy about doing for the sake of one minor warning (and in certain cases it produces another warning about a "redundant variable"):

```js
$("input").each(function(i, el) {
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    const input = el;
    console.log(input.value);
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to deal with this? I did try an inline type definition like this without any luck:

```js
$("input").each(function(i, /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */el) {
    console.log(el.value);
});
```

Here's how each of these looks in the IDE:

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Maybe `@param` will work better, either before or inside the function.

Comment: Just gave it a shot, the only way I could get it to work was to move the anonymous function onto a separate line and then do a full JSDoc block with both parameters before it. Inline didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: adding `@type` annotation before `el` variable as you did is the only way to go unfortunately:(