# how to solve this error: Property 'detailNew' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get this error and I don't know how to fix it, I'm new to using typescript
TypeScript error in /projects/app-colegiado/packages/client/src/components/news/NewsDetail.tsx(6,54):
Property 'detailNew' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.?

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { detailNewReducer }  from './detailNewReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  detailNew: detailNewReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

```
import detailNewActionTypes from "../constants/actionTypes";

export const detailNewReducer = (item = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case detailNewActionTypes.ADD_NEW_DETAIL:
      return  { 
        title: action.item.title, 
        creationDate: action.item.creationDate, 
        id: action.item.id,
      };

     
    default:
      return item;
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const NewsDetail = () => {

    const detailsItem = useSelector((state) => state.detailNew);

    return(
        <>
            <div >
                <img src="#" alt="#">{}</img>
            </div>
            <div>{detailsItem.creationDate}</div>
            <div>{detailsItem.title }</div>
            
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The property 'value' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the `useSelector` hook what the type of the `state` parameter is. `useSelector` is created by calling `createSelectorHook`, which is defined as:

```
export function createSelectorHook(
  context = ReactReduxContext
): <TState = unknown, Selected = unknown>(
  selector: (state: TState) => Selected,
  equalityFn?: EqualityFn<Selected>
) => {
  // ...
}
```

So as you can see, if you don't specify your state type, it will be `unknown`, which is why you get the error.

The easiset thing to do is to [declare your `RootState` type to be the return type produced by running the `getState` on your redux store](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types):

```
// Wherever your store is configured...
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

// Add this!
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Now you can import and use the `RootState` type:

```
import type { RootState } from 'core/store';  // Or wherever your store is

export const NewsDetail = () => {
  const detailsItem = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.detailNew);

  // ...
};
```

Comment: noce corrected this I get another error: TypeScript error in /projects/app-colegiado/packages/client/src/components/news/NewsDetail.tsx(14,31):
Property 'creationDate' does not exist on type 'never'.

I think something needs to be corrected in the   detailNewReducer

Comment: Yep, you need to add types to the state.