# Property rows does not exist on type HTMLElement error TS2339 when loop through table

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

problem

> Property rows does not exist on type HTMLElement error TS2339

when loop through table
on angular 7

I work on angular 7
when loop to table html and compile i get error

> ERROR in src/app/Pages/part-compare/part-compare.component.ts(25,38):
>
> error TS2339: Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
>
> src/app/Pages/part-compare/part-compare.component.ts(27,26): error TS2339:
>
> Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

**How to solve this error please ?**

What I have tried:

```
var table = document.getElementById("CompareParts");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        var Cell = table.rows[i].cells
        this.ACells.push(Cell);
      }
    }
    this.length=this.ACells.length
    for (var x = 0; x < this.ACells.length; x++) {
      this.ARows.push(this.ACells[x]);
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know that the element with the id `CompareParts` is a table -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669404/typescript-problems-with-type-system

Comment: this meaning what i do to solve issue

Comment: so what i do to make typescript recognize table

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: Follow the link from my comment. Read the documentation on how to cast an element to a different type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `document.getElementById` TypeScript doesn't know what is the specific type of the element, so the function returns the generic type HTMLElement. You should cast it to HTMLTableElement.

Try something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("CompareParts") as HTMLTableElement;
```