# How to getElementsByclassName in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the elements by class name from the DOM in typescript. It seems pretty straight forward what I'm doing here but the console shows an error.

```
function showSlides() {
   var i;
   var slides = <HTMLElement[]<any>document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

The expected result should be an array with 3 items and it should change the display style to none, but the actual result is a JS error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.`

Comment: This is not a TS error. It's JS. It just means that `slides[]` at a certain index does not have an element (value), therefore it is `undefined` and you can't read a property of "nothing".

Comment: So what could be the fix for this? I have tried querySelectorAll, but it just works with elements and not with class names.

Comment: What happens when you log the value of `slides`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `<HTMLElement[]<any>`. `getElementsByClass` already returns a array of HTML elements. I've created a Plunkr using your code example and I'm not having trouble > http://plnkr.co/edit/f5XKghZz7aEQLKZdz2af?p=preview

Comment: @PeterBoomsma because when I use document.getElementByClassName I have an error in the code: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element', I think its a TypesCript thing, and thats why I need to cast it as HtmlElement

Comment: @Tofetopo ah yes of course. Check this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686927/typescript-casting-htmlelement

Comment: @Tofetopo Are you using Angular or plain JS?

Comment: I am using Vue, so this code is going into a Vue component.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a JS framework. This is just a simple TypeScript error because you're trying to use a `style` property on a wrong type. Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) objects.

These `Element`s [could be one of a few different types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3263), [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and [`SVGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement) being two common ones.

If you know for sure that all the elements you're looping over are `HTMLElement`s then you can cast to that.

```
const showSlides = () => {
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        const slide = slides[i] as HTMLElement;
        slide.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

If it's possible you'll get back non-`HTMLElement` elements, then you'll need to figure out how to test for them.

One way of doing that might be:

```
const showSlides = () => {
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        const slide = slides[i];

        if (slide instanceof HTMLElement) {
            // slide is a HTMLElement
            slide.style.display = "none";
        } else if (slide instanceof SVGElement) {
            // slide is a SVGElement
            const svgOwner = slide.ownerSVGElement;
        } else {
            // slide is a Element
            const baseUri = slide.baseURI;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Took me a bit. But I've wrestled with this as well.

```
const slides = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('slide'));

for (const x of slides) {
    const y = <HTMLElement> x;
    y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

This should work.

More info on the `for of` loop > https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

If you're using TS you should skip the JS way of looping through a Array and use the TypeScript way.

`getElementsByClassName` returns a array of elements. And you can't use style on a Element. Only on a HTMLElement. So you have to cast the Element into a HTMLElement. If you enclose your `getElementsByClassName` in a Array.from it returns a Element array. From that point you can loop through the Element array in the for loop. And then you cast each object in that Element array to a HTML element array and then you can use `.style` on that object.

If you have questions you can hit me up.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property exists only on `HTMLElement`, yet `slides` is a collection of a broader type: `Element`.

In order to safely manipulate `style`, see if an element is, in fact, an `HTMLElement` first.

```
function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    const slide = slides[i];

    if (slide instanceof HTMLElement) {
      slide.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```